# How to detach firebase Realtime listeners?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using the firebase real-time database version 9, and I use this method to retrieve back data:

```
const refList= ref(
  db,
  `users/${uid}`
);
onValue(refList, (snapshot) => {
  let allData = snapshot.val() === null ? [] : snapshot.val()
});
```

So this is real-time communication therefore this ref has to use a listener. I checked their [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#detach_listeners), they say to use the off() method onto the ref without any code examples.

```
refList.off()
```

Will this remove the listener?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `onValue` call now returns a function that (when called) removes the listener. So:

```
const unsubscribe = onValue(refList, (snapshot) => {
  let allData = snapshot.val() === null ? [] : snapshot.val()
});
```

And then later:

```
unsubscribe();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I search the entire documentation, and I couldn't find that.

Comment: I happened to recall from an API review discussion about it :)
I filed a bug to get this better documented, as it is indeed too hard to find right now. The reference docs were the best I could find: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.md#onvalue

Comment: Great! Even the search bar couldn't find that reference for me. 